# Doctrine2 entity with varchar id don't insert id into database

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, entity

I'm trying to make entity for Doctrine2 in ZF2 Application.
My entity should have id varchar(15) but when I'm trying to create new row, doctrine2 is not pushing this ID into the database.

In entity generated class I have this:

```
 /**
 * Checkpoints
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="checkpoints", uniqueConstraints{@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="sort", columns={"sort"})}, indexes={@ORM\Index(name="country", columns={"country"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
  class Checkpoints
  {
     /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="string", length=15, nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
     private $id;
  // rest of the entity...
```

Is there something I need to change to pass this ID from form into the database in doctrine flush?

Comment: does you ``persist`` the new entity into the entitymanager that it gets managed, before flush?

Comment: of course. it add new row but with id set to null :(
there are many more columns which are inserted. it was empty table so any new insert throw an exception that there is id with null value.

Comment: have you set your mysql column ``id`` with the default option ``auto_increment`` and mark it as ``primary key``? if so, then change your column type in the doctrine entity from ``string`` to ``integer``

Comment: id is not an INT but VARCHAR so it isn't even possible. it have to be varchar and it value should by taken from form.

Comment: as i sayed, but the id value can not set by yourself/form, because you set up for this column an auto generated value wich points and take the value from the ``auto increment`` value of the mysql server

Comment: ok, i understand that. but when i took it from entity or change auto generete to NONE i get something like this:

"Entity of type App\Entity\Checkpoints is missing an assigned ID for field  'id'. The identifier generation strategy for this entity requires the ID field to be populated before EntityManager#persist() is called. If you want automatically generated identifiers instead you need to adjust the metadata mapping accordingly."

My question is - what should i change to have id being passed in insert and not be generated automaticly but be specified by value from form?

Comment: Maybe i should change strategy to none. Insert into entity method setId and before persist set this id to that i get from form... i'm AFK right now so I'll check it later. Do you think it will work??

Comment: look into the doctrine documentation, when ``none`` is set you are responsable to set the id ``setId(...)`` before flush the changes to the db

Comment: Ok. It is working. But even when i have binded object to form i have to make something like this: $checkpoint->setId($checkpoint->getId()); LOL. Probably there is hydrator option to get rid of this. Thx ins0 for help.

Comment: yeap there is look at the ``DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject``

Answer (score 5):

Doctrine handles the `@ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="Identity")` differntly for each database. In case of MySql it is will insert a generated value also known as `AUTO_INCREMENT` resulting in `integer` as ID. Please take a look at http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/basic-mapping.html#identifiers-primary-keys.

In your case you shouldn't be using the `GeneratedValue` annotation including it's strategy. So completely remove it. If you want the ID of your form you could setup a constructor in your entity which will set your ID for that entity.

```
class Checkpoints {

   public function __constructor($id)
   {
       $this->id = $id;
   }

   /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="string", length=15, nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     */
     private $id;
  // rest of the entity...
}
```

Notice that not mentioning the `GeneratedValue` annotation is the same as `GenerateValue(strategy="None")`.

Ofcourse you can set your ID later after creating it, but each instance of this entity needs an ID so it's better to force it to set it by your constructor.

So in your controller you will probaly use something like this

```
if ($form->isValid() {
    $formData = $form->getData();
    $checkpoint = new Checkpoints($formData['id']);
}
```

As you mentioned you would like to set the `ID` by the input of your form. But let me point out that the user can put in duplicates primary keys. In order to catch it you have to check if an object already exists and in that case I would recommend use `\DoctrineModule\Validator\NoObjectExists`. See https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/validator.md about Doctrine validators.

So in order to check if an object exists with the ID you can add this validator to your inputfilter of your form:

```
public function getInputFilterSpecification()
{
    $entityManager = $this->serviceManager->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');

    return array(
        'id' => array(
            'validators' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'DoctrineModule\Validator\NoObjectExists',
                    'options' => array(
                        'object_repository' => $entityManager->getRepository('Application\Entity\Checkpoints'),
                        'fields' => 'id'
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );
}
```

So now we know that the provided `ID` is available for a new `Checkpoints` entity.

Comment: I've done that exacly like u suggested. Only differnce is that my entity object is bind to form so entity object have setter for ID and it is automaticly populated by form.

Comment: Okay well yeah the hydrator can take care of setting the values for you ;) so in that case you don't need to set any ID yourself like I did in the example, within our controller. So if the answer did help you, you can approve it. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the line

```
* @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
```

form your entity and it will insert the record to your entity