# Generate doctrine entity with string id from command line

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony

I like to use the command line to generate entity stubs for doctrine.

For a specific entity the id should be a unique string rather than the default integer with auto increment.

1: How do I specify this in a command like the following?

```
php bin/console generate:doctrine:entity --entity=AppBundle:Game
```

2: In the entity class, is it possible to specify some function that will return this string (similar to the 'strategy' attribute)?
Something a la...

```
@ORM\GeneratedValue(customFunc="getUniqueString")
```

Comment: for point 2 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24827268/doctrine2-entity-with-varchar-id-dont-insert-id-into-database

Comment: I've been looking through the question, but could not find an answer to what I was looking for. It appears that it is not possible to do exactly what I want, and that I should look into setting strategy to none, and make sure to set the id before the item is persisted. (ref: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own ID generator.

Steps:

1. create ID generator class which extends `AbstractIdGenerator`
2. implement `generate` method
3. use `CUSTOM` strategy in your entity definition
4. Add `CustomIdGenerator` annotation with your Id generator class name

Example:

ID generator

```
class UniqueStringGenerator extends AbstractIdGenerator
{
    public function generate(EntityManager $em, $entity)
    {
        // Your logic here
    }
}
```

Entity:

```
/**
* @ORM\Id
* @ORM\Column(name="id", type="string")
* @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="CUSTOM")
* @ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class="MYMODULE\Doctrine\UniqueStringGenerator")
*/
private $id;
```

Comment: This worked nicely, thanks! For the sake of completeness, the UniqueStringGenerator class has to add the following use statements: use Doctrine\ORM\Id\AbstractIdGenerator;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;